# How to distinguish which button is clicked? (Andengine, Android)

Tags: android, andengine

I'm using AndEngine to develop a game with 3 different `buttonSprite`. To use `OnClickListener`, my activity `implements OnClickListener` interface, and overrides `onClick` method and things are good. But pressing every button calls this method! How can I distinguish which button is clicked? I can not simply access the id using `R.id`.

Here is the `onClick` method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(final ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
    this.toastOnUiThread("Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

Here is how my `buttonSprites` look like: (the **`this`** at the end stand for `OnClickListener pOnClickListener`, which calls the `onClick` method)

```
    final ButtonSprite bs1 = new ButtonSprite(button_x1, button_y, this.mButtonNormalTextureRegion1, this.mPressedTextureRegion, this.mDisabledTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager(),  this);
    scene.registerTouchArea(bs1);
    scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
    scene.attachChild(bs1);

    final ButtonSprite bs2 = new ButtonSprite(button_x2, button_y, this.mButtonNormalTextureRegion2, this.mPressedTextureRegion, this.mDisabledTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager(),  this);
    scene.registerTouchArea(bs2);
    scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
    scene.attachChild(bs2);

    final ButtonSprite bs3 = new ButtonSprite(button_x3, button_y, this.mButtonNormalTextureRegion3, this.mPressedTextureRegion, this.mDisabledTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager(),  this);
    scene.registerTouchArea(bs3);
    scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
    scene.attachChild(bs3);
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

The simplest way is to create listener per button. I was not sure what to do when using `this` inside the listener, so not to use the listener's instance instead of the activity instance itself. I was very stupid! Look at the comments below.

Comment: The simplest way is to create listener per button.

Comment: @AlexanderR. Yes, I did that. But inside that when I want to use Intent, the type of `this` is mis-understood: Intent i = new Intent(**this**, Form1Activity.class);

Comment: It thinks `this` is of type `OnClickListener`! But it should be the activity itself.

Comment: hhhh in onCreate() method do: mActivity = this; Define private Activity mActivity; then use Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, Form1Activity.class);

Comment: you can use `YourActivityName.this` .it works.

Comment: If you answer your own question, post a proper answer and accept it (you can answer and accept your own answer). Otherwise your question will still show as unanswered.